# changing a recursive function to a non-recursive

Tags: c, recursion

I have a function below and it is a recursive since it calls itself at the end, but how to I change it non-recursive?

```
int ACR(int q, int*a, int n, int i){
    if(i>=n){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        if(a[i] == q){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return ACR(q,a,n,i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make it iterative: meaning it should involve a loop.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: You have parameters a, b and c. c isn't used but there's this variable called i. Are you sure about this function?

Comment: @TomTanner Looks like the question was incompletely edited.  I've rolled back to the original version as the answers look a bit odd otherwise!

Comment: Wow. I think that's the last time I let students use the internet during an exam. I'm amazed at how fast StackOveflow can answer questions making real-time "take my exam for me but I won't pay you" situations possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop instead

```
int ACR(int q, int*a, int n, int i){
    int j;
    for (j=i; j<n; j++) {
        if (a[j] == q) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Each call to the iterative version of `ACR` tested whether a single element of the array `a` matched the value of `q`.  If we reached the end of the array without a match, we returned 0.  Its easy to translate this into a loop.

Note that `i` may no longer be required as an argument if you always want to search the full array (i.e. start at index 0).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it searches for q in a between indexes i and n, exclusive.

It would be something like:

```
int ACR(int q, int*a, int n, int i) {
    int count;
    for(count =i ; count<n; count++)
         if(a[count] == q)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's the shortest way I could think of:

```
int ACR(int q, int*a, int n, int i) {
    while (i < n && a[i] != q) i++;
    return i < n ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change it? (I suppose it is an exercise...)

Here is something interesting:

Recursive version (yours, with fewer brackets):

```
$ cat acr.c
int has(int q, int*a, int n, int i) {
  if (i >= n)
    return 0;
  else if (a[i] == q)
    return 1;
  else
    return has(q,a,n,i+1);
}
```

Iterative version (mine, but similar to others):

```
$ cat aci.c
int has(int q, int* a, int n, int i) {
  for (; i < n; ++i)
    if (a[i] == q) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Compile both to assembly code and compare:

```
$ diff <(gcc-4.7 -std=c99 -S -o - -O3 acr.c) <(gcc-4.7 -std=c99 -S -o - -O3 aci.c)
1c1
<       .file   "acr.c"
---
>       .file   "aci.c"
9,10c9,10
<       cmpl    %ecx, %edx
<       jle     .L5
---
>       cmpl    %edx, %ecx
>       jge     .L5
```

So rewriting that changed exactly one trivial detail: one checks `n ≤ i` and the other checks `i ≥ n`. (Oh, and the name of the source file is different.)

And here's the same test, with clang:

```
$ diff <(clang -std=c99 -S -o - -O3 acr.c) <(clang -std=c99 -S -o - -O3 aci.c)
1c1
<       .file   "acr.c"
---
>       .file   "aci.c"
12c12
< .LBB0_1:                                # %tailrecurse
---
> .LBB0_1:                                # %for.cond
17c17
< # BB#2:                                 # %if.else
---
> # BB#2:                                 # %for.body
```

Clang puts different comments in the assembler code. Oh, and the filename is still different.